# Term::Readline: encoding-question

Tags: perl, encoding, terminal, readline

When I enter "Müller", on the screen appears "M??ller". How could I fix this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use Term::ReadLine;

my $term = Term::ReadLine->new( 'dummy' );

my $con = $term->readline( ': ' );

say $con;

# On the screen:
# : M��ller                                                                                                                                                   
# Müller
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply `:utf8` layer to filehandles `STDIN` and `STDOUT`, and pass them as arguments to `Term::ReadLine->new()`:

```
binmode STDIN,  ':utf8';
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

my $term = Term::ReadLine->new( 'dummy', \*STDIN, \*STDOUT );
```