# Using Term::ReadLine with Unicode input

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8, readline

I am trying to figure out how to read Unicode input from the terminal using [`Term::ReadLine`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine). It turns out, if I enter a Unicode character at the prompt, the returned string varies depending on various settings. (I am running Ubuntu 14.10, and have installed [`Term::ReadLine::Gnu`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine::Gnu)). For example (`p.pl`):

```
use open qw( :std :utf8 );
use strict;
use warnings;

use Devel::Peek;
use Term::ReadLine;

my $term   = Term::ReadLine->new('ProgramName');
$term->ornaments( 0 );
my $ans = $term->readline("Enter message: ");
Dump ( $ans );
```

Running `p.pl` and typing `å` at the prompt gives output:

```
Enter message: å
SV = PV(0x83a5a0) at 0x87c080
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x917500 "\303\245"\0
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 10
```

So the returned string `$ans` has not set the `UTF-8` flag. However, if I run the program using `perl -CS p.pl`, the output is:

```
Enter message: å
SV = PVMG(0x24c12e0) at 0x23050a0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,POK,pPOK,UTF8)
  IV = 0
  NV = 0
  PV = 0x248faf0 "\303\245"\0 [UTF8 "\x{e5}"]
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 10
```

the UTF-8 flag is correctly set on `$ans`. So the first question is: Why is command line option `-CS` different from using the pragma `use open qw( :std :utf8 )`?

Next, I tested `Term::ReadLine::Stub` with `-CS` option:

```
$ PERL_RL=Stub perl -CS p.pl
```

the output is now:

```
Enter message: å
SV = PV(0xf97260) at 0xfd90c8
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,POK,pPOK,UTF8)
  PV = 0x10746e0 "\303\203\302\245"\0 [UTF8 "\x{c3}\x{a5}"]
  CUR = 4
  LEN = 10
```

and the output string `$ans` has been doubly encoded, so the output is corrupted.. Is this a bug, or is it expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Term::ReadLine` does not read `STDIN`, it [opens new](http://metacpan.org/source/FLORA/Term-ReadLine-1.14/lib/Term/ReadLine.pm#L272) filehandle. And so `use open qw(:std :utf8);` has no effect.

You need to do something like this:

```perl
my $term = Term::ReadLine->new('name');
binmode($term->IN, ':utf8');
```

**Update about `-CS`:**

Option `-C` sets some value to the magic variable `${^UNICODE}`. `-CS` (or `-CI`) option makes expression `${^UNICODE} & 0x0001` true. And `Term::ReadLine` [sets UTF-8 flag on](http://metacpan.org/source/FLORA/Term-ReadLine-1.14/lib/Term/ReadLine.pm#L222) for input string if `${^UNICODE} & 0x0001` is true.

Notice, option `-CS` is different from `binmode($term->IN, ':utf8')`. The first of which sets UTF-8 flag only, and the second encodes string.

Comment: Thanks, but why would it still work with command line option `-CS`?

Comment: I see.. then it would be interesting to know why the `open qw( :std :utf8 )` pragma does not set `${^UNICODE}` variable.. maybe because it is read-only at that point? See https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlvar.pod ..

Comment: @HåkonHægland The `open qw(:std :utf8)` pragma makes `binmode(STDIN, ':utf8')` (and `STDOUT`, and `STDERR`) only.

Comment: Ok, nice to know.. Then I wonder if `Term::ReadLine` should be patched to check if `:utf8` layer is set on `STDIN` maybe?  Also, regarding my last question: Any idea why `Term::ReadLine::Stub` corrupts the string if `-CS` is given?

Comment: I’m not shure this behavior is wrong. What do you mean by speaking about corrupt?

Comment: It transforms `"å"` into two characters `"Ã¥"`.. (octal "\303\203\302\245").. this happens probably because UTF-8 `"å"` is 0xc3 0xa5, If the latter two bytes are encoded again we obtain the corruption..

Comment: If you use `open qw(:std :utf8)` pragma and `-CS` option at the same time then code looks like `perl -MEncode=encode_utf8 -E 'my $s="\xc3\xa5"; utf8::upgrade($s); say(encode_utf8($s))'`. `Term::ReadLine` does `utf8::upgrade()` and `open` does `encode_utf8()`. As a result string will be corrupt.

Answer (score 2):

As explained by Denis Ibaev in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31574072/2173773), the problem is that `Term::ReadLine` does not read `STDIN`, it opens a new input filehandle. As an alternative to calling `binmode($term->IN, ':utf8')`, it turns out one can make either of command line option `-CS` or `use open qw( :std :utf8)` work out of the box with `Term::ReadLine` by supplying `STDIN` as an argument to `Term::ReadLine->new()`, as explained in the answer to this question: [Term::Readline: encoding-question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4967029/2173773).

For example:

```
use strict;
use utf8;
use open qw( :std :utf8 );
use warnings;
use Term::ReadLine;

my $term   = Term::ReadLine->new('Test', \*STDIN, \*STDOUT);
my $answer = $term->readline( 'Enter input: ' );
```